# CONVERT_TZ and european format date

Tags: php, mysql, date

what is the best way to transform unix timestamp in european date format ? 
I use `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(i.opened),  '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS DATE_OUVERTURE` but infortunately it doesn't handle the timezone or maybe my database has a wrong configuration.
I tried the function `CONVERT_TZ` but I noticed that it doesn't like european format.

Comment: Whad do you exactly mean by `european date format` ? Different countries in Europe use various date formats, see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm but it is written in sql in my first post

Comment: Just [set the timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql) when you initialize the connection.

Answer (score 0):

`SET time_zone = 'Europe/Paris'` resolved my problem thanks to your link Vatev.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format a local date according to the local format, you should check out [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) along with [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).